# Build a JNI DLL using MINGW

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mingw, qmake

I am trying to create a DLL that will call Qt (currently I can't use Jambi for the functionality I need). I have a simple Java method:

```
public final native int createChild(int handle);
```

I created C project in Visual Studio Express 2010 and was able to build the DLL.

Then I created a project in Qt creator and moved my sources there. I tried to configure the build to a best of my knowledge but all I get is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tools.proofofconcept.control.EmbedderComposite.createChild(I)I
```

My guess is that symbol is not properly exported from DLL. I added -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ linker arg:

```
g++ -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_  -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -shared -mthreads -Wl -Wl,--out-implib,debug\libqt_integration.a -o debug\qt_integration.dll debug/dllmain.o debug/nativecode.o debug/qmfcapp.o debug/qwinwidget.o debug/moc_qwinwidget.o  -L"c:\Qt\2010.05-rc1\qt\lib" -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should've added following argument:

```
-Wl,--kill-at
```

It will change exported symbols format.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Qt make sure which configuration is used. By default "default" configuration is used (folder "mkspecs/default") and for win32 this causes "UnsatisfiedLinkError".