# JNI and UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm doing my first steps with JNI and tried to write a simple *Hello Java* program, but it fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloJava.dostuff()V
        at HelloJava.dostuff(Native Method)
        at HelloJava.main(HelloJava.java:12)
```

This is my Java class:

```
class HelloJava {
    private native void dostuff();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloJavaDLL");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is from java.");
        HelloJava j = new HelloJava();
        j.dostuff();
    }
}
```

The HelloJava.c is generated using `javah -jni HelloJava`.

The C implementation looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "HelloJava.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJava_dostuff
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
    printf("And this comes from C ! :)\n");
}
```

I compiled it on Windows using gcc to a shared library (.dll).

Now running the Java .class File the Exception from above occurs. **Can you tell me why this error appears ?**

*And by-the-way, can you tell me how I can use JNI with C++ ?*

### UPDATE

Maybe you want to try it yourself ? I really can't find the issue.Here is a link to [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?cdnjhmysk6ep0nc) where you can download a .zip file containing all files (event the compiled ones).

The retried everything but it's still the same issue.
Theese are the steps I did:

1. Write Hello.java
2. Compile Hello.java using `javac Hello.java`
3. Create a header file using `javah -jni Hello`
4. Write the Hello.c file
5. Compile the Hello.c file using
   `gcc Hello.c -shared -o Hello.dll -I"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\include" -I"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32"`
6. Execute Hello.class using `java Hello`

Thanks.

### SOLUTION

Adding `-Wl,--kill-at` to the gcc command fixes the problem, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689074/build-a-jni-dll-using-mingw) here.
Thanks to A.H. for his help !

Comment: Please supply the exact gcc commandline and also the output of `java -version`

Comment: Did you look at any of the 3,500+ results from typing your title into the "Search" box? I'm willing to be that you'll find the answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JNI+and+UnsatisfiedLinkError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check:

- The filename of your library is `HelloJavaDLL.dll` (on Windows)
- The directory of the DLL is either in the library search path (i.e. `PATH` environment variable) or supplied to `java` with `-Djava.library.path=C:\WhereEverItIs`.

The second question: JNI supports *both* C and C++ right out of the box. If you look into the generated header file and in the `jni.h` file you will see this.

Comment: +1, more complete answer than mine. I'll remove mine. You're right, you can use C++ code in the definition of native methods, and you can use JNI functions in C++ code.

Comment: 1. Yes the library is named correctly, 2. I don't think it's not the issue that the library wasn't found, removing the .dll file gives another **UnsatisfiedLinkError** with this message: *Library HelloJavaDLL not in java.library.path* But I'll check it out though, thanks.

Comment: Hence the question about the exact compiler parameters of GCC. There might be some switches, which affect which ABI / calling convention GCC uses by default. And Windows has _some_ of them...

Comment: This is the full gcc command: `gcc HelloJava.c -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32" -o HelloJavaDLL.dll -shared` After compiling I do only run `java HelloJava`. Thanks

Comment: It is for sure not because the library wasn't found.

Comment: I've tried the code from your question (ignoring that media* tingy) on Linux and it works with two caveats: a) call `gcc` with `-shared -fPIC` and b) call `java` with `-Djava.library.path=$PWD`.
Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. :(
gcc gives a warning that fPIC ignores target because "all code is position independent" and java still throws the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. The library **is** loaded, if it wouldn't be the UnsatisfiedLinkError Message would tell me there is no such library, but it doesn't. Man this suckkkkss !! xD Thanks anyway.

Comment: What version of `gcc` are you running? Is either Cygwin or Mingw involved?

Comment: It's MinGW 32 (Windows 7) gcc 4.5.2; I did now also try to do a C++ version and compiled with g++ but its exactly the same error. The library seems to be loaded, but calling the native method from java throws that f**ing error. ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3731/discussion-between-a-h-and-niklas-r)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help ! I've added the answer you told me in the Question itself.