# Java JNI Link Error

Tags: java, c++, g++, swig

I am trying to use swig to generate a c++ library for java. Everything seem to have worked fine so far but I am getting an error.

Here is my java code

```
package Test;

public class Tester {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("example");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(example.fact(5));
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Test.exampleJNI.fact(I)I
at Test.exampleJNI.fact(Native Method)
at Test.example.fact(example.java:22)
at Test.Tester.main(Tester.java:9)
```

Here are the commands I used for Swig

```
swig -c++ -java example.i
g++ -c example.cpp example_wrap.cxx -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include\win32"
g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.dll -Wl,--kill-at -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include\win32"
```

Comment: how does the function `fact` be exported in example.cpp? AFAIK, C++ linkage is different from C.

Comment: Swig does most of the work..

Comment: Can't say for certain, but odds are pretty good this is the exact same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3689074/168175 which is basically calling convention and exporting mismatch between GCC and MSVC